# Cant ssh into running container containing portainer through docker exec

Tags: docker

I cant connect to my running container with portainer.
I tried already executing `docker exec -it <CONTAINER-ID> /bin/bash`. Also changed the shell path many times (/bin/sh, /usr/bin/sh, bash). Every time I get message:

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown

Container was created with command:

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 -p 9000:9000 --name=portainer --restart=always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer-ce
```

Can you tell me why I can't connect to this container only? Portainer web interface is working fine... I thought each container had access to shell, and basic tools such as `ls`

Comment: If the container does not include `/bin/bash` then you can not start it with `docker exec`

Answer (score 2):

Containers may or may not include a shell, depending on how the container was built. Looking at [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/portainer/base) it looks like the base image may be based on a "scratch" image, meaning that there may not be anything in the container other than the code needed to run the portainer service. The image layers [here](https://hub.docker.com/layers/portainer/portainer-ce/latest/images/sha256-77917f339201db91aa25e9498bc130aaf46faa69d16c78088d422df85ce114b1?context=explore) also suggest this is the case.

If you want a shell, you may want to use the `portainer/portainer-ca:alpine` tag. That should give you a container with a full alpine os (and the shell you are looking for). As another note, you may want to try using `/bin/sh` instead as not all images provide a bash shell.

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that you can log in to most containers via /bin/bash or /bin/sh it isn't a general requirement to ship a working shell.  The official portainer docker container [does not have a shell for security reasons](https://github.com/portainer/portainer/issues/2768#issuecomment-471365020) according to [staff](https://github.com/itsconquest).

There are several things you can do.  One would be to build your own docker container image with a Dockerfile and include a shell.  If this is just for a one-off situation, you can also copy a shell (busybox looks like a good candidate) via `docker cp $(which busybox) portainer:/` followed by `docker exec -it portainer /busybox sh`.  This assumes that your running portainer container is indeed called "portainer".

Answer (score 0):

> I thought each container had access to shell, and basic tools such as ls

Only containers that have included a shell has support for a shell.